# Setting 'obscureText' flag to true makes the text field clear when they are not focused-- why?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code to display two textfields, for a username / password entry.

These work perfectly fine and allow a user to type their username then click on the password and type in their password as one would normally expect.

##### BUT

When I add in the `obscureText: true` flag to the password textfield, the behavior changes so that after a user types in their username and then goes to the password field, the entry in the username clears itself.

This is very unusual, and not the way I would expect this to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Column(
                                            children: [
                                                            TextField(
                                                                controller: usernameController,
                                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                                  hintText: 'Username',

                                                                )),

                                                            Container(height:10.0),

                                                            TextField(
                                                                controller: passwordController,
                                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                                  hintText: 'Password',
                                                                )),
                                            ],
                                            ),
```

Comment: are you using a Stateless Widget?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Yep, stateless, I guess it needs state?

Comment: maybe adding an on changed would help, `onChanged: (val) {}` and inside create a setState that updates your controller,  `setState(() => passwordcontroller.text = val);`

Comment: Correct, you do need to have a state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to above advice, the answer was the widget needs to be `Stateful`.

Leaving this here incase it helps someone in the future